# iptables - allow connections to a port only for IP addresses with established state on a different port

Tags: iptables, firewall

I want to allow connections on port x for IP addresses that have a 'established' state on port y.

Is this doable by just using iptables?

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to do?

Comment: I would gather you are trying to create a rules to permit some kind of complex protocol that doesn't have nat helper kernel module.  You may be out of luck.  If that isn't the case, perhaps you can update your question with a more specific example?

Comment: Something like what FTP does.  You need the state module with RELATED,ESTABLISHED by the sounds of it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use port knocking? Open port when a tcp connection is established, could be possible:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "kind of". You'll need to install `ipset` package and ensure that your kernel has `ipset` support.

You'll first have to create an "IP Set" with timeout:

```
ipset create MySet hash:ip timeout 60
```

then add a rule that will reset the timeout for every established packet

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport $port1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j SET --add-set MySet src
```

finally, add a set of rules to allow access to the second port only if the source has been recorded, and drop others

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport $port2 -j Port2_Test
iptables -A Port2_Test -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A Port2_Test -m state --state NEW -m set --match-set MySet src -j ACCEPT
iptables -A Port2_Test -p tcp -j REJECT
```

---

***EDIT***

I just realized that it is also possible to use the `recent` match extension. You do it like this:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport $portY -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m recent --name YThenX --set -j ACCEPT

...    

-A INPUT -p tcp --dport $portX -j Port2_Test

...

-A Port2_Test -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A Port2_Test -m state --state NEW -m recent --name YThenX --rcheck --seconds $timeout --reap $timeout -j ACCEPT
-A Port2_Test -p tcp -j REJECT
```